# My print function from a list returns int values instead of the strings in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am brand new to programming and am working through the "Automate the Boring Stuff" book for Python 3.  I've seen several other people with questions on the 'Comma Code' project but not my specific problem.  I have come up with a 'working' bit to start off but I can't figure out why my print function gives me int values rather than the strings in the list.

```
    def reList(items):
        i = 0
        newItems = str()
        for items[i] in range(0,len(items)):
            newItems = newItems + items[i] + ', '
            print(newItems)
        i=i + 1

    items = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
    reList(items)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please press the `edit` button and reformat the code in your question to match that which you have written.

Comment: See your `for loop` and also indentation

Comment: try adding a debugging print (items[i]) under the for loop to see what the value is. Will give you insight as to what's wrong with this. If you have issues comment and I'll help you later if noone else responds

Comment: Did you mean to do `for i in` instead of `for items[i] in`.

Comment: thank you for the formatting help.

Comment: i think thats what I needed Shreyash!  Im not sure why though?

Comment: is the i somehow implicit?

Comment: is the `i = i + 1` outside the `for` loop?

Comment: yes the i = i + 1 is outside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def reList(items):
    #i = 0 # no need to initialize it. 
    newItems = str()
    for i in range(0,len(items)): # i not items[i]
        newItems = newItems + items[i] + ', '
        print(newItems)
    #i=i+1 # no need to do 
items = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
reList(items)
```

`range(0,len(items))` returns number 0, 1, 2.. upto `len(items)` (excluding)

`for items[i] in range(0,len(items))` was making `items[i]` 0, 1, 2...

That's why it was print numbers.

`for i in range(0,len(items))` make i as 0, 1, 2... and `items[i]` gets you item at `i`th position of the list. So now you get the strings instead of numbers.

A better way would be -

```
def reList(items):
    newItems = str()
    for it in items:
        newItems = newItems + it + ', '
        print(newItems)
items = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
reList(items)
```

Comment: That's great!  Thanks Shreyash!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 for i in range(0,len(items)):
     newItems += items[i]
     if i!=len(items)-1:
         newItems += ','
```

the `+=x` is like writing `newItems = newItems + x`

You want to loop for every value of items, and add a comma at the end, except of course in the last step. That's the purpose of the if.

You can also do this in python with [join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) and think of how you can solve your problem in one line. Welcome to Python :)

Comment: thanks for the welcome.  I can feel my brain growing!